# @angular material theme failed to load on browser

Tags: angular-material

I am running an angular application cloned from git. Found no errors on npm install and ng serve. But my Browser is showing me blank screen. I could see the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) 
>   node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css

Css file is available in the specified path.

My style.css includes:

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

I am new to angular...Please guide me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, in your styles.scss put :

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

You have to replace `../node_modules/` by `~`